# Two divs on one row, only one should scale

Tags: html, css

I have two elements that I want to place next to each other - one is a logo, the other is an "overflow" menu that will display a dropdown when clicked.

I want to have them scale so that the logo is at most 400px wide, and the menu button is always 1.5em wide and tall. **The logo should stay vertically center aligned with the menu button**, and the button should always be at the far right of the parent.

Tried using flexbox but I'm no CSS genius, I can't make it work. *(btw, will we ever see CSS being more like the Android XML layout system? It'd be a breeze to use a `LinearLayout` with some `gravity` and `weight` to do something like this. With CSS it seems you always have to resort to hacks and hard-to-read solutions at some point)*

So this is what it would look like when the logo is at it's maximum 400px width:

[image: Layout on tablet]

And here is what it would look like on a phone, where the logo needs to shrink to make room for the menu button:

[image: Layout on phone]

Comment: Share your code

Comment: You can set a `max-width` of 400px on the logo element.

Comment: Can you share code for what you have tried with flexbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using flexbox.

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/400x50);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 50px;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu-toggle {
  background-color: orange;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="menu-toggle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me in the right direction. The main reason it wasn't working before was that I was overriding some other CSS to make the site header look good on mobile. The main page style used a nested `<a>` and `<img>` instead of a `<div>`. I ended up just making a separate header for mobile and hiding the one that's not supposed to be displayed using a media query, instead of trying to adapt the same one for both layouts. Wish I had done that to begin with...

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do it is here.

```css
.header{
   margin:0px !important;
   padding: 0px !important;
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
   height: 1.5em;
   overflow-y: hidden;
   box-shadow: 0 1mm #aaa 5px;
   vertical-align: middle !important;
   position: relative;
  }

  #img-holder{
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
   height : 100%;
   background-color : blue;
   max-width : 400px;
   min-width : 250px;
   padding: 0px !important;
  }
  #img {
   display: table-cell;
   max-width: 350px;
   min-width: 150px;
   height: 0.75em!important;
   vertical-align: middle;
   background-color: pink;
  }

  #menu-btn{
   display: block;
   margin: auto;
   float: right;
   height: 1.5em;
   width: 1.5em;
   background-color: orange;
   border:none;
   margin: 0px !important;
   padding: none;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="header">
  <div id="img-holder"><span  id="img"> Your Img</span></div>
  <a id="menu-btn"></a>
 </div>
```

Comment: There's no reason for him to have to use `!imporant` here. This is considered bad practice.

Comment: M sorry pal.. i was initially overriding some other class

Answer (score 0):

I used `line-height` and `vertical-align` with `calc`.

**html**:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="menu-button"></div>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x70">
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**:

```
.menu-button {
    background-color: #ffa200;
    float: right;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
}
img {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.logo {
  float: left;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  max-width: calc(100% - 80px);
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/sabeti05/1yg32uqo/